# Passing std::string& and const std::string& as ref in C#

Tags: c#, c++, string, reference, swig

I have following problem. I have a director class where i have following
method:

virtual bool somemethod(const string& param1,int a,int b, string& param2);

I would like to pass std::string& and const std::string& as ref in c#. I
have found following solution
[How to SWIG std::string& to C# ref string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022051/how-to-swig-stdstring-to-c-sharp-ref-string)
, but it doesn't work for me.

In my .i file i call:

```
%include "std_string.i" 
%include "std_string_ref.i" 

%feature("director") DirectorClass; 
%include "DirectorClass.h"
```

And here is example from link provided before (i have changed out to ref):

```
    /*
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * std_string_ref.i
 *
 * Typemaps for std::string& and const std::string&
 * These are mapped to a C# String and are passed around by reference
 *
 *
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

%{
#include <string>
%}

namespace std {

%naturalvar string;

class string;

// string &

%typemap(ctype) std::string & "char**"
%typemap(imtype) std::string & "/*imtype*/ out string"
%typemap(cstype) std::string & "/*cstype*/ out string"

//C++
%typemap(in, canthrow=1) std::string &
%{  //typemap in
    std::string temp;
    $1 = &temp;
 %}

//C++
%typemap(argout) std::string &
%{
    //Typemap argout in c++ file.
    //This will convert c++ string to c# string
    *$input = SWIG_csharp_string_callback($1->c_str());
%}

%typemap(argout) const std::string &
%{
    //argout typemap for const std::string&
%}

%typemap(csin) std::string & "out $csinput"

%typemap(throws, canthrow=1) string &
%{ SWIG_CSharpSetPendingException(SWIG_CSharpApplicationException,
$1.c_str());
   return $null; %}

}
```

Generated code where i have problems:

```
  bool SwigDirector_SomeDirectorClass::somemethod(std::string const 
  &param1,int a, int b, std::string &param2) {
      bool c_result = SwigValueInit< bool >() ;
      unsigned int jresult = 0 ;
      char * jparam1 = 0 ;
      int ja  ;
      int jb  ;
      char** jparam2 = 0 ;

      if (!swig_callbacksomemethod) {
        throw
    Swig::DirectorPureVirtualException("SomeDirectorClass::somemethod");
      } else {
        jparam1 = SWIG_csharp_string_callback((&param1)->c_str());
        ja = deviceId;
        jb = key;
        jparam2= (std::string *) &param2; *<--- here is problem cannot convert
    from string * to char ***
        jresult = (unsigned int) swig_callbackGetConfigItem(jparam, ja, jb,
    jparam2);
        c_result = jresult ? true : false;
      }
      return c_result;
    }
```

So how can i achieve to pass string by reference in director method?

Best Regards,
Nik

Comment: c# and c++ tagged?

Comment: You are trying to call a `virtual` C++ method (very complex problem 1), passing a `std::string` (very complex problem 2). In general I'll say that both problems are nearly unsolvable correctly. C#<->C++ don't "bind" well. As another user always says, use C++/CLI as the glue, or as I always say, create some `extern "C" { }` methods as the glue.

Comment: I am using tool Swig which handle strings and virtual methods. But i have problems with passing by reference. The example that i have provided it works, but not with directors (Swig feature for callbacks).

Comment: Some programmers think SWIG will solve their interop issue, now they have two problems.  Write a C++/CLI wrapper instead.

Comment: @HansPassant Then you'll still have two problems, but at least one problem will be Microsoft blessed :-)